# How do you run a MySQL docker container inside Github Actions?

Tags: php, mysql, database, docker

I'm working on a school project and I want to implement some automatic testing to our code. I've created a docker-compose file that creates three different containers, a `php-apache-environment`, `db`, and `phpmyadin`. I want to test on a push that the docker environment can be built and the database can be successfully queried. When I create the db container in Github Actions the container just stays alive and doesn't allow for any tests to run. Is there a way I can create this container and have it progress to the next steps in the workout instructions?

EDIT: The solution was to use the -d flag. I tried that solution earlier without it working but trying it again seemed to work. Now the database container runs and the execution of the script continues.

For reference here are the files:

php.yml

```
name: PHP Unit Testing

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - feature/*
  pull_request:
    branches: [ "main" ]

permissions:
  contents: read

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Validate composer.json and composer.lock
      run: composer validate --strict

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v3
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress

    - name: Make .env file
      uses: SpicyPizza/create-envfile@v1.3
      with:
        envkey_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.ROOT_PASSWORD }}
        envkey_HOST: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        envkey_NAME: ${{ secrets.USER }}
        envkey_PASS: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        envkey_DATABASE: ${{ secrets.DATABASE }}
        file_name: .env
        fail_on_empty: false

    - name: Create docker containers
      run: docker-compose up db

    - name: Run unit tests
      run: composer test

    - name: Shutdown docker containers
      run: docker-compose down
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
      container_name: php-apache
      build:
          context: ./docker
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
      depends_on:
        db:
          condition: service_healthy
      volumes:
          - .:/var/www/html/
      networks:
        - cs490-local-environment
      ports:
          - 8000:80
  db:
      container_name: db
      image: mysql
      restart: unless-stopped
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${ROOT_PASSWORD}
          MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE}
          MYSQL_USER: ${NAME}
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${PASS}
      volumes:
      - ./docker/database/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create_tables.sql
      networks:
        - cs490-local-environment
      ports:
          - "9906:3306"
      healthcheck:
        test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin" ,"ping", "-h", "localhost"]
        interval: 30s
        timeout: 10s
        retries: 5
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - '8080:80'
    expose:
      - 8080
    restart: always
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: db
    depends_on:
        db:
          condition: service_healthy
    networks:
      - cs490-local-environment
    
networks:
  cs490-local-environment:
    driver: bridge
```

This is also the test that I want to run:
DatabaseTest.php

```
    public function test_database_connection(): void {
        // Looing for .env at the root directory
        $dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__, 1));
        $dotenv->load();

        $connection = new mysqli($_ENV['HOST'], $_ENV['NAME'], $_ENV['PASS'], $_ENV['DATABASE']);

        $this->assertEquals($connection->connect_error, null);
    }
```

Comment: Its a bit ambiguous what "just stays alive" and "doesn't allow tests to be run" - was does this last bit mean? Is there an error? `healthcheck` should have `--protocol tcp` because otherwise success is reported on the start/initialization when it shouldn't be. Not sure why you need phpmyadmin in CI either. Seems unused.

Comment: @danblack The database starts running and then just waits for a connection. This is exactly what I want I just also want it to continue to the next steps and then run the tests that query that database. We're required to use phpmyadmin in the project guidelines so I'm using it for production to edit the database. Locally I have the database get created with an init.sql file every time.